# How to assign a constant value to all records of the pyspark dataframe window

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like this:

```
+-------+-------+
| level | value |
+-------+-------+
|  1    |   4   |
|  1    |   5   |
|  2    |   2   |
|  2    |   6   |
|  2    |   3   |
+-------+-------+
```

I have to create a value for every group in **level** column and save this in **lable** column. This value for every group must be unique, so I use **ObjectId Mongo** function to create that. Next dataframe is like this:

```
+-------+--------+-------+
| level |   lable| value |
+-------+--------+-------+
|  1    |   bb76 |   4   |
|  1    |   bb76 |   5   |
|  2    |   cv86 |   2   |
|  2    |   cv86 |   6   |
|  2    |   cv86 |   3   |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

Then I must create a dataframe as following:

```
+-------+-------+
| lable | value |
+-------+-------+
|  bb76 |   9   |
|  cv86 |   11  |
+-------+-------+
```

To do that, first I used `spark groupby`:

```
   def create_objectid():
       a = str(ObjectId())
       return a

   def add_lable(df):
       df = df.cache()
       df.count()
       grouped_df = df.groupby('level').agg(sum(df.value).alias('temp'))
       grouped_df = grouped_df.withColumnRenamed('level', 'level_temp')
       grouped_df = grouped_df.withColumn('lable', udf_create_objectid())
       grouped_df = grouped_df.drop('temp')
       df  = df.join(grouped_df.select('level_temp','lable'), col('level') == col('level_temp'), how="left").drop(grouped_df.level_temp)
       return df
```

When I used the above code on *spark dataframe* with 2 millions records, it takes about `155` seconds to finish.
I searched and found that `spark window` has better performance. Then, I changed the last function to this one. Because `pandas_udf` needs `arg`, so I just pass one and print it:

```
@f.pandas_udf("string")
def create_objectid_on_window(v: pd.Series) -> str:
    print('v:',v)
    return str(ObjectId())

def add_lable(df):  
    w = Window.partitionBy('level')
    df = df.withColumn('lable', create_objectid_on_window('level').over(w))
    return df
```

But after running the program, I receive this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

**Update:**
I read this question and answers; I do know this is because of the pandas UDF function. Unfortunately, I do not know how to change it.

Would you please guide me how to change the pandas UDF function?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something). Even if not, take some time to understand the cause of the error, it might help you find a solution or at least ask a less generic question.

Comment: What is the full stacktrace ? You did not indicate which line raises this error.

Comment: @Itération122442, the pandas UDF function has the problem.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I read that and did not solve the problem.

Comment: Your question still has the same title, which kind-of indicates a problem that is explained in the given link. There is no [mcve] either. Don't get me wrong, your problem itself is welcome here, but please take the [tour] and read [ask] to understand how to ask a good question.